# Can we give more than one nameFilter criteria in enabling popup in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a popup action in the context menu of the eclipse plugin which is enabled for the file types with extension .txt, Now I want into enable for few more types of the files. So need help in how to configure the nameFilter for the same. I have searched a lot on google but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you talk about the actual classes you are using to clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

While popupMenus has been superceded by org.eclipse.ui.commands and org.eclipse.ui.menus for contributing to menus and toolbars, you might be able to do what you want by using the `filter` element instead of the attribute, and the filters provided by `org.eclipse.ui.IResourceActionFilter`.  See the [popupMenus](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_popupMenus.html) extension point description for information on both types of filters.